# Getting files with same name irrespective of their extension

Tags: python, file-io

**I want to list down all the files with same name irrespective of their extensions.**

`os.walk` results in empty list when I try to search for the file name without extension but when i mention the file name with extension. It list down all the files present in any directory with that same name and extension.

```
def get_all_files(path):
    Datafiles=[]

    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            pathname=os.path.join(root,file)
            Datafiles.append([file,pathname])

    return Datafiles
```

Comment: `os.walk` doesn't do globbing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `fnmatch.filter()` function to recognize the filenames of interest:

```
import os, fnmatch

def get_all_files(path, pattern):
    datafiles = []

    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
        for file in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
            pathname = os.path.join(root, file)
            filesize = os.stat(pathname).st_size
            datafiles.append([file, pathname, filesize])

    return datafiles

print get_all_files('.', 'something.*') # all files named 'something'
```

Note, however, it would be possible, with a few more lines of code, to also make something more generic that supported all of `os.walk()`'s keyword arguments:

```
import os, fnmatch

def glob_walk(top, pattern, **kwargs):
    """ Wrapper for os.walk() that filters the files returned
        with a pattern composed of Unix shell-style wildcards
        as documented in the fnmatch module.
    """
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top, **kwargs):
        yield root, dirs, fnmatch.filter(files, pattern)

# sample usage
def get_all_files(path, pattern):
    for root, dirs, files in glob_walk(path, pattern):
        for file in files:
            pathname = os.path.join(root, file)
            filesize = os.stat(pathname).st_size
            yield file, pathname, filesize

print list(get_all_files('.', 'something.*')) # all files named 'something'
```

Note that the new `glob_walk()` function (as wll as `get_all_files()`) in this version are generators, just like `os.walk()`.